# On Firefox, NVDA will not read the whole words(sentence) which is wrapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing problem in firefox NVDA not read full paragraph it read only one line and when I hover on second-line then it read

the second issue I am facing On Firefox, NVDA will not read the words in table header with the link tag